# ActiveRecord multiple column belongs_to statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have to join a table on multiple columns and want to make that association using the belongs_to association. What is the correct way to make multiple foreign_key, primary_key associations?

```
  belongs_to :performance, foreign_key: 'as_of_date', primary_key: 'as_of_date'
  belongs_to :performance, foreign_key: 'asset_name', primary_key: 'broad_asset_class'
```

or

```
belongs_to :performance, foreign_key: ['asset_name','as_of_date'], primary_key: ['broad_asset_class', 'as_of_date']
```

or something completely different?

What I'm looking for translates to the following sql:

```
Joins PERFORMANCE on ASSET.ASSET_NAME = PERFORMANCE.BROAD_ASSET_CLASS
AND ASSET.AS_OF_DATE = PERFORMANCE.AS_OF_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can repeat `foreign_key`like that.

I think you should include `gem 'composite_primary_keys'` in your Gemfile and do a `bundle install`, so you can do something like:

```
belongs_to :performance, 
           foreign_key: ['as_of_date', 'asset_name'],   #columns in this table
           primary_key: ['as_of_date', 'broad_asset_class'] #columns in remote table
```

And in Performance model:

```
self.primary_keys = ['as_of_date', 'broad_asset_class']
```

Comment: Sorry, the fk/pk [] option doesn't work... it comes accross as "Asset"."['as_of_date', 'broad_asset_class']" = which obviously doesn't exist

Comment: did you include `gem 'composite_primary_keys'` in your Gemfile? and run `bundle install`

Comment: Try to invert foreign_key array with primary_key array on the belongs_to. I cannot help any further without seeing the models and db-schema.